Pass cropping and resizing parameters to Cloudinary from Strapi upload API
I have the following plugin.js file that successfully connects to Strapi upload to Cloudinary:
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    upload: {
        config: {
            provider: 'cloudinary',
            providerOptions: {
                cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME'),
                api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY'),
                api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET'),
            },
            actionOptions: {
                upload: {},
                uploadStream: {
                    folder: env("CLOUDINARY_FOLDER"),
                },
                delete: {},
            },
        },
    },
});

However, having read about Cloudinary's ability to crop/resize images based on parameters I'm keen to include them so I can get the kind of images I need. Documentation is pretty much non-existent so any help would be appreciated!
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/resizing_and_cropping

You need to look into the upload api reference which includes a transformation string option
see here
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_optional_parameters:~:text=transformations%20is%20completed.-,transformation,transformation%20parameters%20can%20be%20specified%20directly%20without%20using%20this%20transformation%20parameter.,-format
so
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    upload: {
        config: {
            provider: 'cloudinary',
            providerOptions: {
                cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME'),
                api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY'),
                api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET'),
            },
            actionOptions: {
                upload: {},
                uploadStream: {
                    folder: env("CLOUDINARY_FOLDER"),
                },
                 transformations : {'w_400,q_auto'}
                delete: {},
            },
        },
    },
});

Note that this means all of these are pre-processed with certain parameters before uploading to the cloud. This may be an anti-pattern as you ideally want full size, quality formats in the cloud which you can then use with the transformation parameters to retrieve based on context.

Thanks - that's helpful, but I guess what I was really referring to was your last sentence, how to adjust what Cloudinary returns? For example its currently small, medium, large but perhaps I'd like to return a custom small, medium and large. Not sure if what I'm talking about is possible.

The transformation and optimization of assets are part of the delivery URL and it is possible to define them in your application (some examples here and here).

exactly what @epasos_573 said, you would pass them when retrieving using the reference you provided as well in your question.
